# Is there any other way to replace consecutive repeating digits with 0 in an integer without converting it to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

We are given an integer which can be large as 10 to the power of 18 and we have to replace all consecutive repeating digits with zero.

I have tried by converting the integer to string but it takes a lot of time in doing type conversion from integer to string. Is there any way to do the function without converting it to string. My code by converting the integer to string -:

```
def replace(l):
    l1 = str(l)
    s = l1[0]
    temp = s[0]

    for i in range(1, len(l1)):
        if l1[i] == temp:
            s += '0'
        else:
            s += l1[i]
            temp = l1[i]

    l = int(s)
    return l
```

Example-: Let integer be 1222433444
Expected output -: 1200430400

Comment: If you don't need more than 10^18, you could use int64 for that.

Comment: [Format your code properl](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)y please!

Comment: I just checked. If this is true "be large as 10 to the power of 18", you should definitely use int64. Well it was flagged with C++. In Python it doesn't matter. It can deal with huge numbers no problem.

Answer (score 1):

What takes time is concattenating `string` to `string` to `string` to `string`. Every time you concat something to a `string` the old one is discarded and a new one is created - this takes computation time. `Strings` in python are *immuteable*.

Use a `list` instead and create the final `string` only once:

```
def replace(l):
    l1 = list(str(l))     # use a list
    v = l1[0]                               # first char is our start v
    for idx,value in enumerate(l1[1:],1):   # we do all the others starting at index 1
        if l1[idx] == v:
            l1[idx] = '0'                   # replace list element
        else:
            v = l1[idx]                     # or replace v if different

    l = int(''.join(l1))               # only create one string & convert to int 
    return l 


print(replace(1222433444))  # input
print(1200430400)           # your expected
```

Output:

```
1200430400
1200430400
```

Answer (score 0):

While using a string *properly* is probably the best solution, you can iterate over the digits directly, without performing a conversion to string at all. There are a couple of ways of doing this. The simplest is probably to start with the largest digit:

```
from math import floor, log10

def replace(n):
    digit_count = floor(log10(n))
    prev = 0
    result = 0
    power = 10**digit_count
    for i in range(digit_count, -1, -1):
        digit = (n // power) % 10
        result *= 10
        if digit != prev:
            result += digit
            prev = digit
        power //= 10
```